# get powershell script output by running it with PHP

Tags: php, powershell

i am running PowerShell scripts via PHP (i know it is not best practice and its not recommended but its a test environment) using the below command

$powershell contains the string below

```
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\xampp\htdocs\list\backend\ps1\check123.ps1"' -Verb RunAs}"
```

executing in PHP as below

```
$powershell = $powershell . ' < nul';
$output = shell_exec($powershell);
echo $output;
```

but can't get the output in any way..
if i execute a simple command such as

```
$output = shell_exec('powershell get-process < nul')
```

it works and it returns the output, 
how can i make it work when running it from a file ?

> one liner powershell execution script that did not work

```
$powershell = 'PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList \'-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\xampp\htdocs\list\backend\ps1\check123.ps1"\' -Verb RunAs';
```

Comment: Change **echo "$output";** To **echo $output;**

Comment: changed it and still it opens a PS window executes the scripts but does not return anything to PHP

Comment: @Vagho Why do you call Start-Process in the first place? Why not just start a single instance of powershell.exe with the `-File` argument?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i tried to make it work but it is not working with a one instance. i will update the one liner code above

Comment: The problem is the original powershell session won't get the output of the new powershell session. If you absolutely have to run it in a elevated context you need to redirect the output to a file and read it from php.